# Ec primes with exponent multiple of $139$ and $215$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If you concatenate in base ten $2^{3336}-1$ and $2^{3335}-1$ you get a prime.
If you concatenate in base ten $2^{75894}-1$ and $2^{75893}-1$ you get a prime.
These are the so-called ec primes which have the form:

$(2^n-1)\cdot 10^d+2^{n-1}-1$ where $d$ is the Number of decimal digits of $2^{n-1}$.

As you can see $3336=(29\cdot 2)^2-28$ and $75894$ are multiple of $139$ and ${} \equiv 1\pmod {29}$.

So I conjecture that there are infinitely many primes of this type with exponent of the form $3336+29\cdot 139\cdot s$.

I did not find any orher prime of this type multiple of $139$. Is It possibile to estimate how big the next prime of this form will be multiple of $139$?
I also noticed that another exponent leading to an ec prime $92020$, which Is multiple of $215$, Is of the form
$3338+29\cdot 139\cdot s$, Beeing $92020=\frac{429^2-1}{2}\equiv 2\pmod {139}$ and $\equiv 3\pmod {29}$. Is It maybe possibile that there are also infinitely many ec primes with exponent of the form $3338+29\cdot 139\cdot s$?

Another exponent leading to an ec prime Is $69660$, multiple of $215$

$69660-6^6=23004$

$92020=4\cdot 23005\equiv 4 \pmod {6^4}$

$92020\equiv 16\equiv 10^3\pmod {451}$, so like $69660$, multiple of $215$, is congruent to $10^n\pmod {41}$. I wonder if It Is Just a coincidence that $92020\equiv 16\pmod {451}$, where $451$ Is an exponent leading to an ec prime.
I mean Is It Just a coincidence that $92020\equiv 16\pmod {41\cdot 11}$ and not $\equiv 16 \pmod{41\cdot j}$, where j Is a Number whose factorization doesn't contain 11?

I also notice that $92020\equiv 16\pmod {51}$ where again $51$ is an exponent leading to an ec prime. It seems to me that all this cannot be random at all.

I think that these exponents are linked among them, but It Is difficult to go ahead.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139594/discussion-on-question-by-pirofotulis-ec-primes-with-exponent-multiple-of-139).

Comment: Curious that $69660\equiv 2\pmod {29}$ and $\frac {(69660-2)}{29}=7^4+1$